# The Levenberg-Marquardt method for nonlinear least squares curve-ﬁtting

Tags: mathematical-optimization

There is a function with unknown coefficient $a$, $b$, $c$
$$t(k)=\frac{1}{a b}(c-arcsinh(\sinh(c \cdot e^{a\cdot k\cdot 2\pi}))$$

I have a measurements   $t_k$  from observed data.

$(t_1 =0.4,t_2 =0.45,t_3 =0.56,t_4 =0.7 , t_5 =0.88)$

therefore  I need to minimize following function to estimate parameters $a$, $b$, $c$

$$S(a,b,c)=\sum_{k=1}^{5}\bigg(t_k -\frac{1}{a b}(c-arcsinh(\sinh(c) \cdot e^{a\cdot k\cdot 2\pi})\bigg)^2 $$

**How can I to identify parameters $a$, $b$, $c$ by using Levenberg-Marquardt  nonlinear least-squares estimation in *Mathematica*?**

```
 t[k_] := (1/(a b))[c - ArcSinh[Sinh[c*E^(a k 2 Pi)]]]

  S[a_, b_, c_] := 
  Sum[(t_k - 1/(a b) (c - ArcSinh[Sinh[c E^(a k 2 Pi)]]))^2, {k, 1, 5}];
```

Comment: You have some typos in your code.  `Sum[t_k` should be `Sum[t[k]` or even `data[[k]]` if `data = {0.4,0.45,0.56,0.7,0.88}` and the outside square brackets in `[c - ArcSinh[Sinh[c*E^(a k 2 Pi)]]]` should be parentheses.  And you're really needing to fit 4 parameters (`a`, `b`, `c`, and the error variance) with just 5 data points?  (I know that measurements can be very expensive but least squares can't provide miracles.)

Comment: @vito `ArcSinh[Sinh[]]` Is this a typo or specifically to complicate the task?

Comment: @AlexTrounev  sorry ArcSinh[Sinh[c]*E^(a k 2 Pi)]

Comment: @vito Please edit the question in order to correct the typos.

Answer (score 5):

We use identity `ArcSinh[Sinh[x]]=x`. Consequently

```
model = (1/(a b)) (c - c*E^(a k 2 Pi));
data = {{1, .4}, {2, .45}, {3, .56}, {4, .7}, {5, .88}};
f = FindFit[data, model, {a, b, c}, k, Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt"]
{a -> -0.0493203, b -> 6.57117, c -> -0.33649}
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[model /. f, {k, 1, 5}]]
```

[image: fig1]

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**

Here is more simple and better model.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
data = {0.4, 0.45, 0.56, 0.7, 0.88};

model[k_] := a + b ArcSinh[c E^k]

cost = Sum[(data[[k]] - model[k])^2, {k, 1, 5}];

fit = NMinimize[cost, {a, b, c}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> {0.000105769, {a -> 0.371878, b -> 0.171929, c -> 0.0633393}}

```
Thread[{a, b, c} = {a, b, c} /. Last@fit];
model[k] // Expand
```

> 0.371878 + 0.171929 ArcSinh[0.0633393 E^k]

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[model[k], {k, 1, 5}]]
```

[image]

You can even try

```
model[k_] := a + b k + c k^2
```

and get good result.

**Original answer:**

```
  ClearAll["Global`*"]
data = {0.4, 0.45, 0.56, 0.7, 0.88};

model[k_] := 1/(a b) (c - ArcSinh[Sinh[c]*E^(a k 2 Pi)])

cost = Sum[(data[[k]] - model[k])^2, {k, 1, 5}];

fit = NMinimize[cost, {a, b, c}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> {0.0260684, {a -> -0.0492263, b -> -0.0885632, c -> 0.00453114}}

```
Thread[{a, b, c} = {a, b, c} /. Last@fit];
model[k]
```

> 229.377 (0.00453114 - ArcSinh[0.00453116 E^(-0.309298 k)])

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[model[k], {k, 1, 5}]]
```

[image]